# using UIWebView along with jqtouch for static html pages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, jqtouch

**Requirement :**

Develop a web-app for iPhone. Ultimate aim is to set-up a webserver.
Temporarily to start with, I want to include the html files in the
xcode project resources (localizing the html) itself and then load
them using UIWebView.

To give a more native look, I have tried using jqtouch. Followed the
steps mentioned in

http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/chapAnimation.html

The app builds and loads fine, but there is no effect of jqtouch, it
looks like a normal html page.

However, when the link to the same index.html (file:///Users/abc/../index.html)
file is opened using safari (in simulator), the effects of jqtouch come up
and a more native feel is provided.

**Question :**

What does safari do, that I have to take care while loading using UIWebView
to make jqtouch take effect ?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved people !**

Problem was in referring the java-scripts and the css themes in the html file.
XCode seems to ignore all the hierarchies and bring all the files into same
folder, the copy bundle resources. I think I will have to create references.

So, in conclusion, nothing extra is required, just load the html through
loadRequest is sufficient.